# How can i save and render array in symfony database?

Tags: php, arrays, symfony

i have an app for pizza ordering. i have entity orders. When i am submitting order i have problem, because i have checkboxes for ingredients and i am saving it as array.

**Entity/Orders**

```
 /**
    * @Assert\NotBlank(
    *           message="please select!")
    * @Assert\NotNull(
    *           message="please select!")
    * @ORM\Column(name="ingredients", type="array")
    * 
    */  
    protected $ingredients;


    public static function getIngredientsOptions(){
        return array('cheese','tomatoes','salami','onions','mushroom', 'bacon','ham','vegetables','peppers','olives');

    }
```

**DefaultController**

```
 private function buildForm($order) {
    return $this->createFormBuilder($order)
        ->add('name','text',array('required'=>false))
        ->add('address','textarea',array('required'=>false))
        ->add('phone','number',array('required'=>false))
        ->add('email','text',array('required'=>false))
        ->add('box','choice',array(
            'choices' => Orders::getBoxOptions()))
        ->add('ingredients','choice',array(
            'choices' => Orders::getIngredientsOptions(),
            'expanded' => true,
            'multiple' => true))
        ->add('delivery','choice',array(
            'choices' => Orders::getDeliveryOptions(),
            'expanded' => true))
        ->add('save','submit')
        ->getForm();
}


 /**
 * @Route("/new", name="new_order")
 * @Template()
 */
 public function orderAction(Request $request)
{
    $order = new Orders();
    $form = $this->buildForm($order);

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $order = $form->getData();

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($order);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->forward('S1500238090PizzaBundle:Default:index');
    }

    return array('form' => $form->createView());
}
```

**index.html.twig**

```
<h3>Orders</h3>
<table border>

<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Address</th>
<th>Phone</th>
<th>E-Mail</th>
<th>Box</th>
<th>Ingredients</th>
<th>Delivery</th>
</tr>

{% for order in orders %}

<tr>
<td>{{order.id}}</td>
<td>{{order.name}}</td>
<td>{{order.address}}</td>
<td>{{order.phone}}</td>
<td>{{order.email}}</td>
<td>{{boxOptions[order.box]}}</td>
<td>{{ingredientsOptions[order.ingredients]}}</td>
<td>{{deliveryOptions[order.delivery]}}</td>
<td>
<a href="{{path('edit_order',{'id':order.id})}}">Edit</a>
<a href="{{path('delete_order',{'id':order.id})}}">Delete</a>
</td>
</tr>

{% endfor %}

</table>

<a href="{{path('new_order')}}">New order</a>
```

i don't know how to save ingredients array correctly and after that render it.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that,I have to change index.html.twig ingredients tag with the following:

```
<td>{% for ingredient in order.ingredients %}
{{ingredient}}
{% endfor %}
</td>
```